# Bad id_token issuer when trying to authenticate with Battle.net OIDC with Cognito

Tags: oauth, openid, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, openid-connect

I've spent the last couple days trying to set up Cognito to use Battle.net OIDC. I believe I am most of the way there. I can see using the cognito hosted UI that it authenticates correctly but then fails, presumably trying to retrieve the token.

The first request to cognito hosted UI:

`https://<removed>.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Blizzard&redirect_uri=https://<my-site-oauth-handler-removed>/oauth&response_type=CODE&client_id=<removed>&scope=openid`

Then the next request is to Battle.net OIDC as expected:

`https://us.battle.net/oauth/authorize?client_id=<removed>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F<removed>.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com%2Foauth2%2Fidpresponse&scope=openid&response_type=code&state=<removed>`

Then the code is passed onto the cognito idpresponse:

`https://<removed>.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse?code=<removed>&state=<removed>`

At this point, if my understanding is correct cognito should try to hit the battle.net `/oath/token` endpoint and then return the id_token and access_token to my redirect_url. It is at the point cognito instead returns an error to my url:

`https://<my-site-oauth-handler-removed>/oauth?error_description=Bad+id_token+issuer+oauth.battle.net&error=invalid_request`

Judging by the lack of documentation for Battle.net OIDC I may be one of a handful trying to use the battle.net OIDC with Cognito. It very well could be a bug with their implementation but I'm trying not to jump to that conclusion.

My best guess right now is that I haven't configured Cognito correctly to make the token POST request. [It needs to use Basic Authentication](https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/using-oauth/authorization-code-flow) with the clientid:password but I can't verify if it's doing that correctly or not since its abstracted away.

Anyway, when I make the request through my app (using amplify to open the hosted UI) it does return but with the following:

```
[ERROR] 51:05.25 OAuth - Error handling auth response. Error: Bad+id_token+issuer+oauth.battle.net
    at OAuth.<anonymous> (OAuth.js:202)
    at step (OAuth.js:52)
    at Object.next (OAuth.js:33)
    at OAuth.js:27
    at tryCallTwo (core.js:45)
    at doResolve (core.js:200)
    at new Promise (core.js:66)
    at __awaiter (OAuth.js:23)
    at OAuth.handleAuthResponse (OAuth.js:181)
    at AuthClass.<anonymous> (Auth.js:1632)
```

Here is all my relevant Cognito configuration:

OIDC Provider:

- Provider Name: Blizzard
- Client ID: [removed]
- Client Secret: [removed]
- Attributes request method: POST
- Authorize scope: openid
- Issuer: https://us.battle.net/oauth

App Client:

- Name: [removed]
- App client id: [removed]
- App client secret: (no secret key)

App Client Settings:

- Enabled Identity Providers: Blizzard
- Callback URLs: https://[removed]/oauth
- Sign out URLs: https://[removed]/oauth
- Allowed OAuth Flows:

  - Authorization code grant
  - Implicit grant
- Allowed OAuth Scopes

  - email
  - openid
  - aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
  - profile
- (I've tried every variation of these and it doesn't appear to change the outcome)

Federated Identity:

- Authentication providers

  - OpenID

    - us.battle.net/oauth

IAM Identity Providers:

- Provider Name: us.battle.net/oauth
- Provider Type: OIDC
- Provider URL: us.battle.net/oauth
- CA Thumbprint: [removed]
- Audience: [my battle.net client id]

I have exhausted my own resources and am asking for any guidance with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by Blizzard issuing their tokens from their well-known endpoints but setting the `iss` field to `oauth.battle.net` which caused Cognito (or any other token validation) to fail hence the error message

`Bad+id_token+issuer+oauth.battle.net`

I brought this up to their API team in Discord and they are releasing a fix on November 25th according to an email send to developers.

> Dear community developer,
>
> Earlier this year, we introduced a new OAuth discovery endpoint which
>   implements the OpenID Connect discovery specification. We would like
>   to deploy a change to the issuer field iss of the id_token during the
>   OpenID authorization flow from oauth.battle.net  to the issuer that is
>   returned by the well-known configuration endpoint JSON response. This
>   would be a potential breaking change to some of the OAuth OIDC clients
>   but it conforms to the OpenID connect specification:
>   https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IssuerIdentifier
>
> Your OAuth client application was identified as one that could be
>   affected by this change.
>
> We are planning to release this change on November 25, 2019.
>
> Here are the steps that you can take to ensure your OpenID Connect
>   client will continue working after the change:
>
> Navigate to one of the well-known configuration endpoints below which
>   corresponds to the region where your client application operates and
>   check the "issuer" field.
>
> If the issuer field matches the configured issuer for your OAuth OIDC
>   client then your client is compatible and you are already compliant
>   and do not need to make any changes.
>
> If the issuer field from the well-known configuration endpoint is
>   different than the issuer set in your client configuration, please
>   change the issuer to match the well-known configuration endpoint.
>
> If your client supports the OpenID discovery endpoint standard, you
>   can configure it to read all necessary settings from the well-known
>   configuration endpoint. Your OAuth client should self-configure.